# What is the best approach in python for opening two or more pickles and then determining the intersection of entries between them?

Tags: python-2.7, statistics, pickle, bioinformatics, intersection

I apologize in advance, as I cannot explain what I want to do without mentioning some biological terms. I will try to explain them in the most rudimentary way possible.

In the code I have been developing lately, a user writes in the name of a gene (i.e. a sequence of compounds that act as a "blueprint" for a cell to build things from) or a transcription factor (i.e. a kind of protein that binds to genes to help them get expressed in a cell), and after some processing, a dictionary is built, which is subsequently stored in to pickles. Afterwards, the the pickle is opened, read, and a table is built using the information stored in the pickles.

I should mention that when one enters in a gene or transcription factor (which I will abbreviate to TFs), the dictionary that is built have keys of TFs or genes respectively, with values being of an array of scores. These scores reflect the probability of a TF or gene binding with each other at a certain position along the gene, and if no positive scores are yielded between a certain gene and TF, then it is excluded from the dictionary (note: all my gene sequences have the same length).

Although my basic code pipeline works fine, it only works for one gene or one transcription factor at a time. One aspect of my code that I really wanted to allow the user one or more inputs at one time. However, to do this, I need to do two things:

1. Make an intersection between the contents of each pickle, and pull out entries that all pickles have in common.
2. Process the scores in the values so that they represent the value of a certain TF binding to two or more genes at a given position.

My issue with the first item in the list above  is that I am not sure whether I should intersect the pickles after I've opened and dumped them in my script, or whether it would be computationally less complex to intersect them while they are still pickles.

My issue with the second item in the list above is that I don't know what kind of mathematics I should implement in order to process these values so that they properly reflect the two or more probabilities.

Can anybody recommend me the most prudent approach to take in these issues?

Comment: can you make some sample  data for these two files and the required output? Its hard to tell without any data. Maybe its because I don't have any biological knowledge.

Comment: @grubjesic yeah I don't really know how I would upload some sample data for people to look at ....  could recommend me a medium where I can upload some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best way after unpickling is a sets library.

- Cast your data to list and to set
- Use intersection

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: I did see Set objects while I was looking around, but I wasn't sure if that's what I wanted, given that I might need to make 2, 5, or even 100 sets, and then make intersections of them all. Furthermore, I'm not even sure if, from a theoretical standpoint, making these intersections produces relevant results. Regardless, I will still read deeper into these sets and see if they can at least combine common genes/TFs, and then I will figure out what to do about the associated statistical scores.

Comment: Yep, this turned out to be the best method! I used: common_genes= set.intersection(*given_sets), in order to make an intersection between 2, 5, or even 100 sets. As for the scores, we decided ultimately to leave them out of the final analysis for a variety of reasons, namely because combining them together will not be biologically relevant.

Comment: Good to hear it :)